# Problema em inserir registros no Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11c

Estou tendo problemas para inserir registros no Oracle, abaixo segue o `insert` que utilizo:

```
insert into COMPRAS (id, valor, data, observacoes, recebido)
values (id_seq.nextval, 200, '19-FEB-2008', 'MATERIAL ESCOLAR', '1');
```

Entretanto gerou esse erro SQL;

```
 Erro ao iniciar na linha 1 no comando  
    insert into COMPRAS (id, valor, data, observacoes, recebido)  
    values (id_seq.nextval, 200, '19-FEB-2008', 'MATERIAL ESCOLAR', '1')  
    Relatório de erro:  
    Erro de SQL: ORA-01858: foi localizado um caractere não numérico onde se esperava um numérico  
    01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"  
    *Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was  
               incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where            
               anumber was required by the format model.    
    *Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the  
               elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

Minha tabela esta assim:

**`COMPRAS`**

```
Nome        Nulo     Tipo         
----------- -------- ------------ 
ID          NOT NULL NUMBER       
VALOR                NUMBER       
DATA                 DATE         
OBSERVACOES          VARCHAR2(30) 
RECEBIDO             CHAR(1)
```

Foi criada assim a tabela:

```
create table compras (
    id number primary key,
    valor number, 
    data date, 
    observacao varchar2(30),
    recebido char check (recebido in(0,1)));

    CREATE SEQUENCE ID_SEQ;
```

Como faço para resolver isso?

Comment: Você já tentou usar a função `TO_DATE()`? `TO_DATE('19-Feb-2008', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')`

Answer (score 1):

Você está tentando inserir um `VARCHAR` em um campo `DATE`
converta em data utilizando `TO_DATE` conforme o comentário do Eduardo Almeida

```
TO_DATE('19-Feb-2008', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')
```